graal_create_isolate fuction return error: GraalVM native-image
I would like to create shared library(.dll) form java code with graalVM. When I use the shared library which is created from java code by native-image, the execution result has succeeded or failed depending on the execution environment.
When the execution result fails, graal_create_isolate fuction return 23. I would like to know how to look up the meaning of this 23 meaning.
The generated header(graal_isolate.h) by native-image command says "a non-zero value on failure.", but the meaning of each value is not written in that header. Please could someone help me? thanks a lot.
[excecution environment and result]

Windows Server 2022(version: 21H2, OS build: 20348.197)
result: error
Windows Server 2022(version: 21H2, OS build: 20348.469)
result: success
Windows Server 2022(version: 21H2, OS build: 20348.2227)
result: error
Windows 10 Enterprise(version: 22H2, OS build: 19045.4412)
result: success

[execution result]

success
main.exe
count = 1234
error
main.exe
initialization error(ret = 23)

[build process]
javac Sample.java
native-image -o Sample --shared
cl /I .\ .\main.c Sample.lib
[code]

Sample.java

import org.graalvm.nativeimage.IsolateThread;
import org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.function.CEntryPoint;
import org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.type.CCharPointer;
import org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.type.CTypeConversion;
public class Sample {
  @CEntryPoint(name = "getCount")
  private static int get_count(IsolateThread thread) {
    return 1234;
  }
}


main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Sample.h"
int main(void) {
  graal_isolate_t *isolate = NULL;
  graal_isolatethread_t *thread = NULL;
  int ret = graal_create_isolate(NULL, &isolate, &thread);
  if (ret != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "initialization error(ret = %d)\n", ret);
    return -1;
  }
  printf("count = %d\n", getCount(thread));
  if (graal_tear_down_isolate(thread) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "shutdown error(ret = %d)\n", ret);
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

[build environment]

GraalVM
graalvm-jdk-17.0.11+7.1
Vidual Studio
Visual Studio 2022
cl --version
Microsoft(R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.36.32535 for x64

My expectation is that it will work in any environment.

After making the following changes, the error no longer occurs.
Before:
javac Sample.java
native-image -o Sample --shared
cl /I .\ .\main.c Sample.lib

After:
javac Sample.java
native-image -o Sample --shared -march=compatibility
cl /I .\ .\main.c Sample.lib

